# How to pass parameters to Main() C# in visual studio for mac

Tags: c#

I've looked at the different resources for other editions of visual studio but it's not clear to me how to call Main with an arg here

```
using System;

namespace helloWorld
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hello " + args[0]);
            }
            else
            { 
                Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In debug mode, or in general?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Arguments can be supplied to your application within Visual Studio for Mac by right clicking on your console application in the right hand pane then going `Options` > `Run` > `Configurations` > `Default` where you'll see an `Arguments` text field.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I can specify arguments here but for some reason Visual studio is not passing the values to the application

Comment: Having this problem as well. Worked for me to create a new run configuration with the arguments in this solution. Remember to select the new configuration (next to the 'play' button in the main window)

Answer (score 6):

For some reason, the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41775575/4751173) from @JosephWoodward isn't working for me. It looks like a Visual Studio bug, but I do have a workaround; the consequence is that you have to provide the arguments *every time* you want to start the app.

1. From the menu, choose Run -> Run With -> Custom Configuration ...

[image]

2. In the dialog, enter the arguments:

[image]

3. If you want to *debug* instead of run, you need to change the Run Action at the bottom:

[image]

Comment: This worked but it's a pain. I discovered that if I start the app by selecting "Start Debugging Item" from the project context menu the parameters that I set in the project configuration get sent. Not sure why the toolbar button and the run menu doesn't do this, I feel like it's a clue to the problem but I can't figure out the answer.

Comment: Having this problem as well. This solution worked, but is too troublesome. Worked for me to create a new run configuration with the arguments (as it is supposed to work). Remember to select the new configuration (next to the 'play' button in the main window)

Answer (score 1):

As Joseph Woodward stated, you supply them in the arguments field under
`Project Options > Run > Configurations > Your_configuration_here`.

Note that a project rebuild is necessary for these arguments to successfully be passed into Main - otherwise `args` will continue to be null.

Comment: Project rebuild does not help in my case, args is still empty. Worked after I created a new configuration. So weird...

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I think that it would be good to provide an answer for those looking to use the terminal.

When installing Visual Studio:Community Edition on MacOS you are given a suite of tools.
Including [csc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/command-line-building-with-csc-exe) and [mono](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/supported-platforms/macos/).

So to run a C# console program like the one below you will need to use both tools:

```
using System;

namespace helloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string name = args[0];
            Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}", name);
        }
    }
}
```

Then compile the C# project by running csc:

```
$ csc Program.cs
```

If there are no errors csc will then create an executable file .exe, use mono to run the executable and pass the arguments:

```
$ mono Program.exe Bob
Hello Bob
```

With these two tools you can compile, and execute the C# program.

Answer (score -1):

The arguments to main will be command line parameters.
If running from within visual studio, you can setup the the

`command line arguments` property in the "configuration properties" of your project.

For running it from command line, just invoke the exe file with parameters.

```
Path/to/YourProg.exe arg1 arg2
```

Comment: I was able to figure it out from your answer but what I had to go through was Options then Run then Configurations and then set the Arguments field

Comment: @ZackLucky glad it worked. I didn't remember the exact path to those settings. Mark the answer as expected if it helped.