# How to save run configurations - Visual Studio Mac

Tags: asp.net, macos, visual-studio, configuration, save

I am developing an asp.net application on macOS with Visual Studio for Mac, and I can specify a custom run configuration.

There seems to be no way to specify a run profile, where all arguments and settings in the custom configuration are saved, instead of reentering command line arguments every time.

Is there a way to do this easily in VS for Mac? Or is that feature not available yet...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass parameters to Main() C# in visual studio for mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41775512/how-to-pass-parameters-to-main-c-sharp-in-visual-studio-for-mac)

Comment: Slightly different. That is for a console app. I did not see the "Run/Configurations" menu when making a web project :/ Unless I'm looking in a different place and missed it (then I'd LOVE to be made aware)

Comment: It's in the Project Options (double-click on the project in the Solution pad).

Comment: Can you "save" this, and have it executed every time? or do you have to put it in every time? what about having different "profiles" for the run configurations and switching between them?

Comment: For me, that depends on the application type. For console apps, I can't get it to work but it does work for web apps.

Comment: Oh it doesn't work with console apps? I would need that too for a later project... gah

Comment: It does seem to be a bug that is ignored by the VS team... 

The arguments aren't saved or aren't passed to the application unless you enter them every time. 

Maybe i'll have to make a basic "bootstrapper" to simply call my application via main of a different project? 

Blah...

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately you can't save it but there is workaround for this.
You get the args in the main, just change it to your configuration and put it to code when you need it.

string[] args = new[] {..}