# Visual Studio for Mac Console Application .net Core 2 command line arguments

Tags: macos, visual-studio

I wanted to test something using a console app and some command line arguments. I know of the run options in Visual Studio 2017 for Windows where you can specify the command line arguments, but the same settings in Visual Studio for Mac does not seem to work. I have provided a few command line arguments in the run configuration for the default configuration in the arguments entry, but upon debugging, the args[] is empty. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

TIA,
John.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass parameters to Main() C# in visual studio for mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41775512/how-to-pass-parameters-to-main-c-sharp-in-visual-studio-for-mac)

Answer (score 2):

Rebuild your project for command line arguments supplied in:

> Project Options > Configurations > [Configuration name] > Arguments to be passed into your `Main` successfully.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173/).

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but I think that it would be good to provide an answer for those looking to use the terminal, I did write about this after seeing there were no answers in an even older [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41775512/how-to-pass-parameters-to-main-c-sharp-in-visual-studio-for-mac).

When installing Visual Studio:Community Edition on MacOS you are given a suite of tools.
Including [csc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/command-line-building-with-csc-exe) and [mono](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/supported-platforms/macos/).

So to run a C# console program like the one below you will need to use both tools:

```
using System;

namespace helloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string name = args[0];
            Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}", name);
        }
    }
}
```

Then compile the C# project by running csc:

```
$ csc Program.cs
```

If there are no errors csc will then create an executable file .exe, use mono to run the executable and pass the arguments:

```
$ mono Program.exe Bob
Hello Bob
```

With these two tools you can compile, and execute the C# program.